# Chrome Extensions: Extension not working - Content Script Communicating with Background Script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, dom-events, content-script

I am working on a Chrome Extension which changes the Browser Action Icon to "red.png" or "green.png" (which are both saved in the same directory as all other files) when the browser app detects sound is being played from an `<audio>` html5 tag.

My logical thought process is: User opens page, script starts running on page which constantly (perhaps a `setInterval()`) checks for if the sound is running. If the sound is running, change the icon to "green.png", else, set it to "red.png".

The way I am checking if sound is being played is this:

```
 if (audio.duration > 0 && !audio.paused)
```

Where audio is a variable holding the `<audio>` element.

Here is my code:

```
    manifest.json file:

{
    "name": "Creative Sound Dedection",
    "description": "Creatively detects sound.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "red.png"
    },
    
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches" : [ "<all_urls>" ],
            "js" : [ "myscript.js" ]
        }
    ],
    
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

---

```
background.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var playing = request.playing;

    if(playing == true)
    {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"green.png"});
    }else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"red.png"});
    }
});
```

---

```
myscript.js

function isAudioPlaying(var audio)
{
    if (audio !== false && audio.duration > 0 && !audio.paused)
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

function getAudio()
{
    if(document.getElementById("myAudio")) return document.getElementById("myAudio");
    
    return false;
}

//if audio is playing: tell background that audio is playing, otherwise, tell it audio is not playing
function sendInfo()
{
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        "playing": true
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    setInterval(sendInfo, 500);
});
```

I'm looking for help with why this isn't working and how to correct it, I'm very new to Chrome Extensions development as well as Javascript (although not necessarily new to programming).

Also if you can think of other ways (better) to accomplish the same task please let me know.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Furthermore, the expression `playing == true` will always evaluate to `false`, since `playing` is a string. So:

```
// Change that:
var playing = request.playing;
if (playing == true) {...

// To this:
var playing = request.playing;
if (playing == "true") {...
```

---

`setInterval(sendInfo(), 500);` means:
*"Every 500 milliseconds, execute the **value returned by** `sendInfo()`."*

Since you want to say:
*"Every 500 milliseconds, execute the **function named** `sendInfo`."*

chagne the above to:
`setInterval(sendInfo, 500);`

---

BTW, **`chrome.extension.sendRequest/onRequest`** are obsolete and should be replaced with **[`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage)/[`onMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)** instead.
Besides being obsolete, the former does not properly load an event page (a.k.a. non-persistent background-page) before sending the message, so this might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Will edit this part, thanks, although still doesn't work and I don't know where to begin looking for the errors.

Comment: @AndrewB: Please, see my updated answer for one more possible cause of error (and let me know if it solved the problem). If the problem persists, try looking for any errors in the console logs of the background page and the webpage where the content script is being injected.

Comment: Hello, just updated the code I am using in the original post.

It still does not work (if it was working the image would change from red to green, which does not happen).

The page it is testing on is a minimal page I a made myself, with two audio tags and a h1 tag, one of the audio tags has the id "myAudio".

Thank you for your patience, I am quite busy so getting back to you and testing it sometimes takes time!

Comment: Just poking about the page, my content_script: myscript.js doesn't seem to be working.

I put in 'alert("true")' into the eventlistener, "DOMContentLoaded" and nothing happened. I then commented that listener out and put it on the outside of everything, again nothing happened.

Comment: @AndrewB: I updated my answer with one more cause of error :) What you report about your content script is strange. Did you refresh the page after reloading the extension ? Do you get any errors in the web-page's console.log or in the background-page's console log ?

Comment: Regarding the request.playing part, if its only two equals doesn't it compare the value but not the type, and three equals compares the type as well as the value? I need to leave again but I will get back to you with more testing done soon!

Comment: @AndrewB: Regarding comparison using `==`, **ECMAScript 5.1** defines the **[Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)**. In short, `"true" == true` comes down to `NaN == 1` which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help I just got it working, I'll post up my editted code. I'll give you the answer since it wouldn't have worked without all your input!